# Basic Python: Passing a string as an input to a function

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am just starting off with python. I have 4 variables F_1, F_2, F_3 and F_4. Each containing a matrix in them. I want to count the non-zero values in each of them. So i wrote a loop.

```
f_1 = thresh1[1:mr, 1:mc]
f_2 = thresh1[1:mr, (mc+1):width]
f_3  = thresh1[(mr+1):height, 1:mc]
f_4 = thresh1[(mr+1):height, (mc+1):width]

b_1 = thresh2[1:mr, 1:mc]
b_2 = thresh2[1:mr, (mc+1):width]
b_3  = thresh2[(mr+1):height, 1:mc]
b_4 = thresh2[(mr+1):height, (mc+1):width]

for i in range(1, 5):
    n1 = "f_"
    n2 = "b_"
    num = str(i)
    n1 += num
    n2 += num

    r = cv2.countNonZero((n1)/cv2.countNonZero(n2))
    print r
```

I want to pass the concatenated strings `n1` and `n2` as inputs to the equation `cv2.countNonZero((n1)/cv2.countNonZero(n2))`.

Here F1 is a binary image (F as in foreground) and B1 is also binary image (B as in Background). I am trying to compute the ratio of non zero pixels in foreground vs background.

r should be calculated for F1/B1 and in the next iteration F2/B2 ... so on

Comment: What equation in `r`?  I'm a little confused, as it seems like you're dividing `n1` (which is a string) by an integer (`cv.countNonZero(n2)`).  Does this actually compile?  Can you perhaps give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think the question is quiet confusing,  you want to pass `n1` to a function whose value is a string and lit's value is same as the name of the variable `f_1`. But your actual intention is to pass the variable value of `f_1`. And you are doing it so that you can loop over and pass multiple variables of that series.

Comment: Yes that was the original intent. Sorry about the lack of clarity but AP nortons suggestion works perfectly. Guess i need to learn the data structure syntaxes in python asap! Thank you all for taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in that you're trying to use strings to reference variable names.  This is considerably difficult to do; you're better off using lists to contain your images.  That is, instead of trying to reference `f_1`, `f_2`, etc, create a single list called `f` that contains each of the images.

For instance, instead of the code you have at the top, use:

```
f = [
  thresh1[1:mr, 1:mc],
  thresh1[1:mr, (mc+1):width],
  thresh1[(mr+1):height, 1:mc],
  thresh1[(mr+1):height, (mc+1):width]
]

b = [
  thresh2[1:mr, 1:mc],
  thresh2[1:mr, (mc+1):width],
  thresh2[(mr+1):height, 1:mc],
  thresh2[(mr+1):height, (mc+1):width]
]
```

Now you can reference what you were calling `f_1` before with the code `f[1]`.

Now, inside your loop, you can use:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    r = cv2.countNonZero(f[i])/cv2.countNonZero(b[i])
    print r
```

I recommend you look into how to use lists in Python, as this is a fundamental datastructure.  Also, there is a difference between `"f_1"` (which is a string) and `f_1` (which is a variable named `f_1`).  You can't (easily) go between the two.

Answer (score 1):

```
f_1_nz = f_1[f_1 != 0].size
# etc.

r_1 = f_1_nz / b_1_nz
# etc.
```

Ideally you'd put f_1 etc. into a list and iterate over it, instead of defining new names for each, see the answer by @apnorton.

So, in the end:

```
for ff, bb in zip(f,b):
    f_nz = ff[ff != 0].size
    b_nz = bb[bb != 0].size
    print f_nz/b_nz
```